# Importing table of contents from another org file?

Tags: org-mode

**Specific Use Case**: I have two files, *index.org* and *blog.org*. I would like to include the table of contents of *blog.org* in *index.org*.

The "obvious solution" to me is to use org-babel to inject html upon export (probably with JQuery+NodeJS). However, this seems kind-of hacky to me. Is there a better, more idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [#+INCLUDE](https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html) derivative? In *index.org* add the following line:

```
#+INCLUDE: blog.org::*TOC
```

In *blog.org* put your TOC under a *TOC header.

Feel free to explore the #+INCLUDE documentation for similar approaches.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the included table of contents enumerates the headers in _index.org_, not _blog.org_.